# Sourcing Excel files with gatsby-source-filesystem

Tags: gatsby

Not sure, if I'm on the right way? We use Microsoft Excel files with product information. So I write a transformer plugin to extract needed information and create JSON nodes.

I expected to get the raw Excel content (XLSX) with `loadNodeContent`.

```
// gatsby-node.js
...
const contentExcel = await loadNodeContent(node)
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.load(contentExcel);
...
```

Accessing the content with [ExcelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#xlsx) throws an error

> Corrupted zip: missing 1197 bytes.

Does `gatsby-source-filesystem` unzip the .xlsx file or process the content somehow?

**Edit:**

As a temporary workaround, I did this. It also proofs that the Excel file is not corrupted:

```
// gatsby-node.js
...
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(node.absolutePath);
console.log(workbook.worksheets[0].rowCount); // -> 83, reports the correct row count
...
```

Comment: XLSX files are in a zip wrapper. Perhaps one of the files is actually corrupted?

Also, have you tried https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-excel/

Comment: @firxworx perhaps I can achieve what we need. I'll examine the plugin. Probably it's much easier and cleaner for our use case to process the Excel files directly. We do not need all information stored in the files and often we need another representation. But the workaround (see above) reading the file again is clumsy too.

Comment: @firxworx The plugin does basically the same thing. It reads the Excel-binary from the file system. I'm pretty new to Gatsby and related technologies. But I conclude that gatsby-source-filesystem does not store raw, unprocessed binary data.

Comment: Hmm too bad. I've only personally used the filesystem plugin with markdown files. I'm not sure what it does to files and if it processes them in some way, unless someone on SO knows off-hand, you might have to check the source